# "Quick" save in electron with a conformation dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-system, electron

I have implemented a "quick" save for my electron app. There has to be a better way to achieve what I am doing.

The `MessageBox` will always be triggered on a save as command. If the user selects save (Ctrl+S), I'm basically keeping a variable to hold if a file has been loaded from the file system or not. If a file has been loaded I take the array from fs and convert into a string and use that as the filename for the quick save.

If no file has been uploaded, this means my gantt area is clear and the `SaveDialog` box will be triggered since this isn't a loaded file. A little code to further explain. Before the quicksave function the filename is either undefined or a string from the fs array and stored in `quickSaveFilename`.

```
// dirty quicksave
const quickSave = () => {
  let saveData = gantt.serialize();
  saveData = JSON.stringify(saveData, null, '\t');
  if (quickSaveFileName === undefined) {
    dialog.showSaveDialog(
      {
        defaultPath: `C:\\Users\\${process.env.USERNAME}\\Documents\\`,
        filters: [
          {
            name: 'json',
            extensions: ['json'],
          },
        ],
      },
      (filename) => {
        if (filename === undefined) {
          return;
        }
        fs.writeFile(filename, content, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            dialog.showErrorBox(
              'Save Failed',
              `An error occured saving the file ${error.message}`,
            );
            return;
          }
          dialog.showMessageBox({
            type: 'none',
            title: 'Ganttron',
            message: 'The chart was successfully saved',
            buttons: ['OK'],
          });
        });
      });
  } else {
    fs.writeFile(quickSaveFileName, saveData, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        dialog.showErrorBox(
          'Save Failed',
          `An error occured saving the file ${error.message}`,
        );
      }
      dialog.showMessageBox({
        type: 'none',
        title: 'Ganttron',
        message: 'The chart was successfully saved',
        buttons: ['OK'],
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this in electron?

Answer (score 1):

We can make the code simpler with a `saveFile` function

```js
function saveFile(filename, data) {
    fs.writeFile(filename, content, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            dialog.showErrorBox(
                'Save Failed',
                `An error occured saving the file ${error.message}`,
            );
            return;
        }
        dialog.showMessageBox({
            type: 'none',
            title: 'Ganttron',
            message: 'The chart was successfully saved',
            buttons: ['OK'],
        });
    });
}

const quickSave = () => {
    let saveData = gantt.serialize();
    saveData = JSON.stringify(saveData, null, '\t');
    if (quickSaveFileName === undefined) {
        dialog.showSaveDialog({
                defaultPath: `C:\\Users\\${process.env.USERNAME}\\Documents\\`,
                filters: [{
                    name: 'json',
                    extensions: ['json'],
                }, ],
            },
            (filename) => {
                if (filename === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                saveFile(quickSaveFileName, saveData);
            });
    } else {
        saveFile(quickSaveFileName, saveData);
    }
};
```